# Clang built from source compiles C but not C++ code

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, clang

I've recently compiled clang on windows (host: x86_64-pc-windows64 ; compiler: i686-pc-mingw32 ; target: i686-pc-mingw32).
The CMakeCache (for the config) can be found: [here](https://gist.github.com/3d0e0a6c9049b500de31)
My issue is that while clang works fine (for C), clang++ (for C++) will "successfully" compile and link, but the resulting program itself won't run and will exit with an error code 1. Here's a sample below (oh-my-zsh):

```
➜  bin  cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        return 0;
}
➜  bin  cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout<<"Hello World!"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
➜  bin  ./clang++ test.cpp -o a.exe
➜  bin  ./clang test.c -o b.exe
➜  bin  ./a.exe
➜  bin  ./b.exe
Hello World!
➜  bin
```

as is visible here, b.exe (in C) works fine, but a.exe (C++), while compiled and links, gives no output.
Could anyone hint me unto why this is so, and how can I fix it?
Note: the pre-compiled snapshot of clang for windows (also 32 bit) works fine with my current path configuration.
Note: a.exe (C++, failed) returns non-zero.
DATA:
CLANG VERSIONS:
Snap: `clang version 3.5 (208017)` ; Comp: `clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)`
LLVM FILES: [snapshot](https://gist.github.com/b7a6d06fd2fba2dce45e) ; [compiled](https://gist.github.com/e73b961659a9dc0064de) ; [diff](https://gist.github.com/a037d2a2bf8bd8233010)
PREPROCESSING FILES: [snapshot](https://gist.github.com/1e42cb709e78d073a595) ; [compiled](https://gist.github.com/540bec7df80591af8c22) ; [diff](https://gist.github.com/50837619aedd4a95c6aa)
ASM FILES: [snapshot](https://gist.github.com/3752b43ee778214771db) ; [compiled](https://gist.github.com/ad8c32e27b7f7c007d91) ; [diff](https://gist.github.com/220283e82cd99911b976)
VERBOSE OUTPUT: [snapshot](https://gist.github.com/97110a6d3145276ca898) ; [compiled](https://gist.github.com/8f41c0187649d6a6c3b5)

Comment: Have you tried having a look at the assembler or LLVM-IR output (`clang++ -S test.cpp` or `clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp`) to see if it contains anything "unusual". Exactly which source code did you compile?

Comment: both of them. a.exe is the result of the c++ source code (test.cpp) ; b.exe is the result of the c source code (test.c) . C works, C++ doesn't.

Comment: Neither `clang++ -S test.cpp` not `clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp` produce any output.

Comment: You should get a file called test.s and test.ll respectively

Comment: I only have a test.ll file.

Comment: The .ll file looks pretty much the same as the one I'm getting on my Linux machine. Here's mine: https://gist.github.com/Leporacanthicus/ced9c11993c91dbfc4b9

Comment: When I asked "what source", I meant what LLVM+Clang source code... Looks like it's the 3.4 source, which should be OK...

Comment: 3.4 source final release of llvm and clang.

Comment: At this point, I'd fire up a debugger and see where it goes in the output functions - it's probably a bit messy, but I can't see anything else obvious.

Comment: update with diff : noticing that right file has unique entry points that left does not.

Comment: I can't actually spot any REAL difference, only names being mangled differently.

Comment: Shingetsu, looks like there is some problem in the c++ libraries. Start from `-v` option to linking step.

Comment: @osgx since libc++ isn't working on windows yet, I'm using the mingw32 one. It works fine with the binary release of clang (snapshot) ; so I don't see how it could go wrong with just about the same config of a compiled one...

Comment: Shingetsu, so you can compare your clang with snapshot, starting from assembler and -v from linking. It is very strange that you have no "test.s" - so you can compare disassembler of two versions of `a.exe`.

Comment: @osgx I managed to get a test.s (not sure what I did wrong the first time). The diff between the compiled and snapshot .s files are up. (as well as the verbose outputs of the linking process). Unfortunately I'm not good at the details at this level, so I can't really help much with my own problem.

Comment: Shingetsu, Thank you, your help is to post right logs. But you added `-v` to the assmebly step (it is done without linking), not to the link step. Add `-v` to the compilation string `./clang++ test.cpp -o a.exe`, which includes linking. You can also add `-Wl,-verbose` in other pair of runs to see exact paths to used libraries.

Comment: @osgx updated with full verbose of basic compile (as asked)

Comment: Shingetsu. thank you. There is the difference between ll files: `x86_thiscallcc` specifier for `_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E` function call. Can you post two full asm files? Also, compare preprocessing results from two clang versions (`clang++ test.cc -E -o test.E`)

Answer (score 2):

You new clang uses different (incorrect) [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), not the `x86_thiscallcc`.

`snap.s` from good clang:

```
movl    $__ZStL8__ioinit, %ecx
calll   __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev

movl    %esp, %ecx
movl    $__ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, (%ecx)
movl    %eax, %ecx
calll   __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
```

Same code from your custom clang, `comp.s`:

```
leal    __ZStL8__ioinit, %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
calll   __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev

movl    %eax, (%esp)
movl    %ecx, 4(%esp)
calll   __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
```

and several other.

In llvm bitcode (`*.ll` files) right calling convention is marked with `x86_thiscallcc` in function definitions and after `call` instruction:

```
<   call void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"* @_ZStL8__ioinit)
>   call x86_thiscallcc void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"* @_ZStL8__ioinit)

< declare void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"*) #0
> declare x86_thiscallcc void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"*) #0
32c33
< declare void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"*) #0
> declare x86_thiscallcc void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"*) #0

<   call void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"* @_ZStL8__ioinit)
>   call x86_thiscallcc void @_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev(%"class.std::ios_base::Init"* @_ZStL8__ioinit)

<   %3 = call %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* %2, %"class.std::basic_ostream"* (%"class.std::basic_ostream"*)* @_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_)
>   %call1 = call x86_thiscallcc %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* %call, %"class.std::basic_ostream"* (%"class.std::basic_ostream"*)* @_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_)
< declare %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E(%"class.std::basic_ostream"*, %"class.std::basic_ostream"* (%"class.std::basic_ostream"*)*) #0
> declare x86_thiscallcc %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E(%"class.std::basic_ostream"*, %"class.std::basic_ostream"* (%"class.std::basic_ostream"*)*) #0
```

In preprocessed file I see the difference. In `snap.E` many functions are defined with `__attribute__((__cdecl__))` and in `comp.E` they are defined with just `__cdecl__`. You should check why the definitions are different after preprocessing. I think, new clang may predefine different set of macro (gcc had `-dM -E` option to dump predefined, not know how to do this in clang). Or your clang just uses different headers (or different versions of headers, you can list used headers with `-H` option of clang compilation).

Other way is to check, is `__attribute__((__cdecl__))` should be equal to `__cdecl__`, and does newer version of clang change anything in handling them.

Comment: I doubt it's the clang version, since 3.4 worked on tons of platforms as well.

Comment: PS: what is your exact version of clang 3.5? There were several clang bugs for calling convention http://llvm.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&f0=OP&f1=OP&f2=product&f3=component&f4=alias&f5=short_desc&f6=status_whiteboard&f7=content&f8=CP&f9=CP&j1=OR&o2=substring&o3=substring&o4=substring&o5=substring&o6=substring&o7=matches&product=clang&query_format=advanced&v2=cdecl&v3=cdecl&v4=cdecl&v5=cdecl&v6=cdecl&v7=%22cdecl%22&version=trunk&version=3.4&order=changeddate%2Cbug_id

Comment: clang version 3.5 (208017)

Comment: So is there any way to fix this? (Without going to 3.5 since it (svn) doesn't compile nicely on my machine (yet).)

Comment: Please, list both full versions, used in this question.

Comment: Added to DATA: section.

Comment: ^ ; seriously, can anything be done with clang 3.4? (considering it _does_ work on *nix and such)

Comment: Yes, seriously you can do an "update" operation on your 3.4, and switch to 3.5. Or you can continue digging in the headers (why the __cdecl__ was changed, it should be some macros misdefined by your clang) and in clang's bugs. You can also download prebuild 3.4 from llvm and compare with your own build.